# WCF application isn't running on IIS Express 7.5

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-express

I have a WCF service developed on .NET framework 4. My dev machine is running Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012 and I already published the service at IIS 8.

Now I need to publish the service on a Windows XP machine. I'm getting several errors on IIS 5.1, so I gave up to use this version and I'm trying to use IIS Express 7.5 with VS2010.

The service gets up with no problems, but I cant acess the WSDL cause it says that metadata is disabled.

What can I do to activate metadata on my WCF service?

Follows the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
       <configSections>
          <sectionGroup name="SAP.Middleware.Connector">
            <sectionGroup name="ClientSettings">
              <section name="DestinationConfiguration"                     type="SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationConfiguration, sapnco"/>
            </sectionGroup>
          </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
        <SAP.Middleware.Connector>
          <ClientSettings>
            <DestinationConfiguration>
              <destinations>
                <add NAME="XXX" USER="XXX" PASSWD="XXX" CLIENT="XXX" LANG="EN"           ASHOST="mc0.sap.XXX.com" SYSNR="XXX" MAX_POOL_SIZE="XXX" IDLE_TIMEOUT="XXX"/>
                <add NAME="QA" USER="XXX" PASSWD="XXX" CLIENT="XXX" LANG="EN"           ASHOST="XXX" SYSNR="XXX" MAX_POOL_SIZE="XXX" IDLE_TIMEOUT="100"/>
              </destinations>
            </DestinationConfiguration>
          </ClientSettings>
        </SAP.Middleware.Connector>
        <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
        </startup>
        <appSettings/>
        <system.web>
          <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
          <httpRuntime/>
        </system.web>
        <system.serviceModel>
          <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
              </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
          </behaviors>
          <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
          </protocolMapping>
          <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        </system.serviceModel>
        <system.webServer>
          <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
          <!--
              To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
              Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
            -->
          <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
        </system.webServer>
      </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share configuration information for your services and service and endpoint behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this topic wich instructs to use WEBMATRIX to host a WCF application in IIS Express. It worked perfectly for me.

Hope it can help somone else!

http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should check if in your config file that you enable mex.

e.g. (mex though http).

In your service behavior you should enable the following option

```
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

In your endpoint list you should add the following

```
<endpoint address="/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Save your config and rerun.